# php code generator for mysql tables

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

It is the Nth time I have to write versyy similar code to update/edit/remove records from tables using php/phpmyadmin/mysql.

My tables has some 1toMany relations and manyToMany relations
(like users, books , userbooks tables)

Is there a generator for these kind of things ? How could I speed up this "boring" and "repetitive" task ?

reagrds

Comment: have you tried any php frameworks like Yii or CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 2):

use a migration manager: https://github.com/search?type=Everything&language=PHP&q=migration&repo=&langOverride=&x=0&y=0&start_value=1

a full on framework is better, but this will get you started quicker.

Answer (score 1):

[The `phpscaffold` might interest you.](http://www.phpscaffold.com/)